# Different profile based on membership selection

Tags: wordpress, civimember, profile, contribution-page

When our members join or renew online, I want to use a different profile to capture different information depending on the membership type. For example, if someone selects an "Educator" membership, I'd like to use custom fields to capture the programs they offer and the audiences they reach - but those fields aren't relevant to the other membership types, so I don't want to use the same profile for all types.

Is there a way to select a certain profile based on the membership type selected, or do I need to create separate contribution pages for the different membership types?

I am using CiviCRM 5.18.2 with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at the Caldera Forms CiviCRM plugin. This will allow you to use conditions within a caldera form to show and hide fields (and make them required) based on the type of membership selected. The plugin contains multiple processors to allow you to add contacts, memberships, etc. in CiviCRM.

The plugin is available in the WordPress repository. Here is a link to the plugin info: https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with CiviCRM and Wordpress. But one direction of looking for a solution is that use Contribution Pages for membership signup and renewals and then use a different contribution page for different membership types.